# Can my JavaScript code be edited at runtime by (malicious) users?

Tags: javascript

Can my JavaScript code be edited at runtime by (malicious) users, even when it is uploaded in a web hosting site?

For example if I declare a variable in my script something like:

```
var myvalue = 2;
```

I want to know if it can be edited to:

```
var myvalue = 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: yes.

Anyone can open the browser's Developer Tools and change values, execute arbitrary code, remove or change or edit anything they like.

So if there is anything crucial in your application where an invalid value could cause a security or data validation issue, then, if that data (or data which is derived using that value) is submitted to the server, it must be re-validated using server-side code (which of course cannot be changed) before being accepted.

---

P.S. Bear in mind that any edits to the code or variable values will only persist until the next time the page is re-loaded. When the page is refreshed, the JavaScript and HTML files will be downloaded again from the server and all code and variable values are reset to their starting state. Assuming there are no other security vulnerabilities in your server, then a malicious user cannot edit the original source code files which are stored there. They can only change the copy which gets loaded into the browser.